# Automating Deployment of Lambda-based Applications

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline

I checked the tutorial at below link and tried that. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/automating-deployment.html

Its working for me, but how to deploy the environment variables and configuration changes related to that lambda. From tutorial I can understand how to deploy code changes but I am not sure how to deploy configuration changes.

Answer (score 0):

For having Lambda pull configuration information there are a number of options:

- For very basic configuration you can simply use environment variables which can be set during CLI call as per docs (rep prevents me from adding more than two links so you'll have to google "lambda environment variables" to get it)
- Lambda can read from [SSM Parameter Store](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html), though that's normally used for pulling in configuration information for EC2 instances (DB strings and what not). However if you're primarily going serverless that's one way to do it
- You can use DB of choice (RDS/DynamoDB) to pull/store data. Just remember that if you pass free tier limits you get hourly charges.
- You can use format of choice (JSON, YAML, CSV, etc.) stored in an S3 bucket and have python load that (it will go against your call allocation)
- For complex linking of Lambda functions you might want to consider [Step Functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-state-machine-data.html)

As for how you automate the above, it will really depend on what your existing automation is. There's either the CLI to orchestrate the whole thing, or using a scripting language of your choice with the appropriate AWS SDK.

Comment: Thanks. I am planning to use YAML file to set up configuration. Is there any link or tutorial for that. As I am new to lambda and cloud getting stuck.

Comment: @NileshPharate when you say YAML configuration are you talking about CloudFormation YAML templates? Also which of the above are you planning to use for your configuration?

Comment: Yes, CloudFormation YAML templates. I am using S3 bucket approach for my configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than manually perform the steps described in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/automating-deployment.html, I wrote a CloudFormation template that performs the same functions. In other words, you can deploy my template and the result is a newly-created Code Commit repository and associated Code Pipeline which builds and deploys any SAM template you define to a new CloudFormation stack. All that you need to do is add a buildspec.yml and samTemplate.yaml to the newly-created Code Commit repo and push your changes.

My template is available at the link below. Please note it's an early draft and has much room for improvement... but it does closely mirror the AWS guide linked above: https://github.com/matwerber1/cloudformation-pipeline-template

Here's the template code, samTemplate.yaml:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Creates Private Code Commit repo and Deployment Pipeline to CloudFormation
Parameters: 
  ProjectNameParameter:
    Type: String
    Default: myProject
    Description: "the name to assign to your newly-created code repo, build project, pipeline, and IAM resources."

  CodeBuildS3BucketParameter:
    Type: String
    Default: "myCodeBuildS3Bucket"
    Description: "a pre-existing S3 bucket in which to store Code Build artifacts."

  CodePipelineS3BucketParameter:
    Type: String
    Default: "myCodePipelineS3Bucket"
    Description: "a pre-existing S3 bucket in which to store Code Pipeline resources."
Resources:

  MyRepo:
    Type: "AWS::CodeCommit::Repository"
    Properties: 
      RepositoryName: !Sub '${ProjectNameParameter}'

  CloudFormationRole:
   Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
   Properties:
    RoleName: !Sub "${AWS::Region}-${ProjectNameParameter}-cloudformation"
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
              - cloudformation.amazonaws.com
          Action:
            - "sts:AssumeRole"
    Path: "/"
    Policies:
      - PolicyName: cloudformation-service
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Action:
              - "*"
              Resource: "*"
              Effect: Allow

  CodePipelineRole:
   Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
   Properties:
    RoleName: !Sub "${AWS::Region}-${ProjectNameParameter}-codepipeline"
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
              - codepipeline.amazonaws.com
          Action:
            - "sts:AssumeRole"
    Path: "/"
    Policies:
      - PolicyName: codepipeline-service
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Action:
              - "codecommit:GetBranch"
              - "codecommit:GetCommit"
              - "codecommit:UploadArchive"
              - "codecommit:GetUploadArchiveStatus"
              - "codecommit:CancelUploadArchive"
              Resource: "*"
              Effect: Allow

            - Action:
              - "s3:GetObject"
              - "s3:GetObjectVersion"
              - "s3:GetBucketVersioning"
              Resource: "*"
              Effect: Allow

            - Action:
              - "s3:PutObject"
              Resource:
                - "arn:aws:s3:::codepipeline*"
                - "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk*"
              Effect: Allow

            - Action:
              - "codedeploy:CreateDeployment"
              - "codedeploy:GetApplicationRevision"
              - "codedeploy:GetDeployment"
              - "codedeploy:GetDeploymentConfig"
              - "codedeploy:RegisterApplicationRevision"
              Resource: "*"
              Effect: Allow

            - Action:
              - "elasticbeanstalk:*"
              - "ec2:*"
              - "elasticloadbalancing:*"
              - "autoscaling:*"
              - "cloudwatch:*"
              - "s3:*"
              - "sns:*"
              - "cloudformation:*"
              - "rds:*"
              - "sqs:*"
              - "ecs:*"
              - "iam:PassRole"
              Resource: "*"
              Effect: Allow

            - Action:
              - "lambda:InvokeFunction"
              - "lambda:ListFunctions"
              Resource: "*"
              Effect: Allow

            - Action:
              - "opsworks:CreateDeployment"
              - "opsworks:DescribeApps"
              - "opsworks:DescribeCommands"
              - "opsworks:DescribeDeployments"
              - "opsworks:DescribeInstances"
              - "opsworks:DescribeStacks"
              - "opsworks:UpdateApp"
              - "opsworks:UpdateStack"
              Resource: "*"
              Effect: Allow

            - Action:
              - "cloudformation:CreateStack"
              - "cloudformation:DeleteStack"
              - "cloudformation:DescribeStacks"
              - "cloudformation:UpdateStack"
              - "cloudformation:CreateChangeSet"
              - "cloudformation:DeleteChangeSet"
              - "cloudformation:DescribeChangeSet"
              - "cloudformation:ExecuteChangeSet"
              - "cloudformation:SetStackPolicy"
              - "cloudformation:ValidateTemplate"
              - "iam:PassRole"
              Resource: "*"
              Effect: Allow

            - Action:
              - "codebuild:BatchGetBuilds"
              - "codebuild:StartBuild"
              Resource: "*"
              Effect: Allow

  CodeBuildRole:
   Type: "AWS::IAM::Role" 
   Properties:
    RoleName: !Sub "${AWS::Region}-${ProjectNameParameter}-codebuild"
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
              - codebuild.amazonaws.com
          Action:
            - "sts:AssumeRole"
    Path: "/"
    Policies:
      - PolicyName: codebuild-service
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Action:
              - "logs:CreateLogGroup"
              - "logs:CreateLogStream"
              - "logs:PutLogEvents"
              Resource:
              - !Sub "arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:/aws/codebuild/${ProjectNameParameter}"
              - !Sub "arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:/aws/codebuild/${ProjectNameParameter}:*"
              Effect: Allow

            - Action: 
              - "s3:PutObject"
              - "s3:GetObject"
              - "s3:GetObjectVersion"
              Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::codepipeline-${AWS::Region}-*"
              Effect: Allow

            - Action: "ssm:GetParameters"
              Resource:  !Sub "arn:aws:ssm:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:parameter/CodeBuild/*"
              Effect: Allow

            - Action: "s3:PutObject"
              Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${CodeBuildS3BucketParameter}*"
              Effect: Allow

  MyBuild:
    Type: "AWS::CodeBuild::Project"
    Properties: 
      Artifacts:
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
      BadgeEnabled: false
      Environment:
        ComputeType: BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL
        Image: "aws/codebuild/python:3.5.2"
        Type: LINUX_CONTAINER
      Name: !Sub '${ProjectNameParameter}'
      ServiceRole: !Ref CodeBuildRole
      Source:
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
      TimeoutInMinutes: 60

  MyPipeline:
    Type: "AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline"
    Properties:
      ArtifactStore:
        Location: !Ref CodePipelineS3BucketParameter
        Type: S3
      Name: !Sub "${ProjectNameParameter}"
      RestartExecutionOnUpdate: false
      RoleArn: !GetAtt CodePipelineRole.Arn
      Stages:
        - Name: "Source"
          Actions:
            - ActionTypeId:
                Category: Source
                Owner: AWS
                Provider: CodeCommit
                Version: "1"
              Configuration:
                RepositoryName: !GetAtt MyRepo.Name
                BranchName: master
                PollForSourceChanges: true
              Name: Source
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: MyApp
              RunOrder: 1

        - Name: "Build"
          Actions:
            - ActionTypeId:
                Category: Build
                Owner: AWS
                Provider: CodeBuild
                Version: "1"
              Configuration:
                ProjectName: !Ref MyBuild
              InputArtifacts:
                - Name: MyApp
              Name: "Build"
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: MyAppBuild
              RunOrder: 2

        - Name: "Staging"
          Actions:
            - ActionTypeId:
                Category: Deploy
                Owner: AWS
                Provider: CloudFormation
                Version: "1"
              Configuration:
                ActionMode: CHANGE_SET_REPLACE
                StackName: !Ref ProjectNameParameter
                Capabilities: CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
                ChangeSetName: MyChangeSet
                RoleArn: !GetAtt CloudFormationRole.Arn
                TemplatePath: MyAppBuild::NewSamTemplate.yaml
              InputArtifacts:
                - Name: MyAppBuild
              Name: "build_changeset"
              RunOrder: 3

            - ActionTypeId:
                Category: Deploy
                Owner: AWS
                Provider: CloudFormation
                Version: "1"
              Configuration:
                ActionMode: CHANGE_SET_EXECUTE
                StackName: !Ref ProjectNameParameter
                Capabilities: CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
                ChangeSetName: MyChangeSet
              Name: "execute_changeset"
              RunOrder: 4
```